# restore a specific AWS Elasticsearch database snapshot backup on a different machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, database-backups

curl -XGET 'elasticsearch-domain-endpoint/_snapshot/repository/_all?pretty'

below are the list of indices snapshot, how do i restore a particular snapshot, on to another machine, using Elasticsearch 6.0.1, kibana provided by AWS

```
{
      "snapshot": "2018-04-08t04-43-08.c5da6a35-8158-4799-a58d-0baf0a432275",
      "uuid": "cJ2XzzDHSROh-SmiJ1mbHA",
      "version_id": 6000199,
      "version": "6.0.1",
      "indices": [
        "test-index2",
        "l",
        "test-index",
        ".kibana",
        "test-index1",
        "s"
      ],
      "state": "SUCCESS",
      "start_time": "2018-04-08T04:43:08.113Z",
      "start_time_in_millis": 1523162588113,
      "end_time": "2018-04-08T04:43:14.992Z",
      "end_time_in_millis": 1523162594992,
      "duration_in_millis": 6879,
      "failures": [],
      "shards": {
        "total": 26,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 26
      }
    },
    {
      "snapshot": "2018-04-09t04-43-07.b2e215dc-5bea-446c-812a-4a2f0dddad9c",
      "uuid": "2ib6BIdURSmoL1OlUpzIPg",
      "version_id": 6000199,
      "version": "6.0.1",
      "indices": [
        "test-index2",
        "l",
        "test-index",
        ".kibana",
        "test-index1",
        "s"
      ],
      "state": "SUCCESS",
      "start_time": "2018-04-09T04:43:07.639Z",
      "start_time_in_millis": 1523248987639,
      "end_time": "2018-04-09T04:43:14.590Z",
      "end_time_in_millis": 1523248994590,
      "duration_in_millis": 6951,
      "failures": [],
      "shards": {
        "total": 26,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 26
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create the same S3 repo on your other ES cluster (the exact same command as when you initially created the repository on your source cluster)

```
PUT _snapshot/repository
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "your_bucket"
  }
}
```

And then you can restore any snapshot very simply with:

```
POST /_snapshot/repository/2018-04-08t04-43-08.c5da6a35-8158-4799-a58d-0baf0a432275/_restore
```

Comment: I tried the above mentioned POST command, I am getting a different error now

Comment: {
  "Message": "Your request: '/'http://xyzes-554.us-t-1.es.amazonaws.com/_snapshot/cs-automated/xyz-04-17t04-43-11.xyz-ff98-4cd8-a259-xyz/_restore'' is not allowed by Amazon Elasticsearch Service."
}

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html), it should support `_snapshot` queries

Comment: Is there any thing I need to do get access to the cs-automated backup directories that pointed to the S3 bucket.

Comment: you need to make sure that folder is in the `path.repo` setting in the `elasticsearch.yml` config file

Comment: I haven't checked the .yml file, let me check it and update, but if I am using aws ES {} then will the .yml concept work.

Comment: were you able to copy data from one ES to another? @vinsentparamanantham